# Meaning of "no poco"

Tags: traducción

I was reading *El almohadón de plumas* by Horacio Quiroga this morning and ran into the following sentence:

> La casa en que vivían influía no poco en sus estremecimientos.

I can make out the construct and it seems fairly straightforward. Except the **no poco** bit. Isn't **no** always used with a verb? I have never seen it used with an adverb or adjective before. The way I could translate this was:

The house that they lived in influenced no little in their shudders.

...which makes no sense whatsoever to me! Is there any idiomatic construct at play here? I looked up **poco** and **estremecimiento** and found nothing out of ordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed an interesting case where the position of the words makes it harder understand the meaning. As you correctly stated, *no* is to be used (at least here) to refer to the verb *influía*.

So in fact the sentence could be:

> La casa en que vivían **no influía poco** en sus estremecimientos.

But then, why this use? Well, it emphasizes *poco* to contrast it, when they want to mean *a lot*. This means that you can translate the sentence into something more direct like:

> The house *where* they lived in influenced **quite a lot** in their shudders.

Or keeping the emphasis (not sure if it is 100% idiomatic in English):

> **It wasn't little** how the house *where* they lived in influenced in their shudders.

(Note I translated *en que vivían* to *where they lived*.)

Comment: We do also say: the house where they lived had no little influence on their shudders. It does sound a bit old-fashioned to me but it might fit the style of the rest of the book (which I do not know).